# Usando SPA (Single page application) e botão voltar do navegador

Tags: lado-do-cliente, front-end, lado-do-servidor, single-page-application

Alguém que trabalhe com SPA sabe qual é a melhor forma de trabalharmos com o botão voltar do browser?

Por exemplo, temos uma listagem de usuários e o detalhamento destes usuários através de um click. Quanto estamos na "página" de detalhamento de algum usuário precisamos que, ao clicar no botão voltar do navegador, voltasse para a listagem de usuários.

Answer (score 5):

Há duas formas de fazer isto:

## Hash Links

Se dá pelo uso do hash links, como `www.meusite.com#conteudo`. Sendo que `conteudo` muda a cada transição que você quer que seja retornável. Por ex: você teria `site.com#listagem` e quando clicá-lo irá deve mudar para `site.com#detalhamentoItem=15`. Essa técnica se aproveita do fato que o tudo após o '#' é considerado âncora e não causa uma recarga da página.

### Prós

- O pró deste método é a compatibilidade, pois funciona desde os anos 90.
- Funciona muito bem para páginas que escritas puramente em js (sem backend).

### Contras

- Links "feios";
- Observar a mudança do hash pode ser extremamente cansativa em browsers mais antigos (e ignorá-los acaba com sua vantagem). Entretanto há dezenas de bibliotecas que fazem esse trabalho sujo para você. Pessoalmente, eu gosto do http://plugins.jquery.com/hashchange/ e utilizei ele em alguns projetos.

## HTML5 history API

Método mais novo e que permite controle total da url. Veja mais em http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

### Prós

- Perfeito quando seu servidor consegue gerar uma página como `site.com?detalhamento=15` ou `site.com/detalhamento/15`, mas também pode servir o resultado via AJAX (que economiza banda). Assim tem-se a velocidade do ajax sem perder a navegação por histórico;
- Controle total das url que serão tão bonitas quanto seu servidor e sua criatividade permitirem.

### Contra

- Usar este é método é quase impossível sem uma linguagem serverside;
- É html5. Diga tchau à compatibilidade.

Comment: Não é quase impossível usar history API sem uma linguagem serverside. O difícil é gerenciar o SEO com roteamento javascript, independente do tipo de roteamento javascript usado. Alias, o suporte google fala sobre isso em https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=en